# Spam through autobiographer badge?

Tags: support, badges, spam

### [Discussion on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303746/178209)

I noticed this today when looking at [badges](https://superuser.com/help/badges).

Obviously these accounts will probably be nuked by some type of spam script, but for now it's mildly annoying that I can't celebrate others' accomplishments.

[image]

Comment: This is being discussed on MSE, actually: [Spam Profiles are getting my goat. Could we have better tools for mods to deal with profile spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w)

Comment: @Catija ah, my bad. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to apologize for. Just letting you know it's further up the chain. ;)

Comment: I noticed this today as well, it's still going on, lots of spam insurance user accounts

Comment: Thanks for the pointer with the Autobiographer badge. Helped me cleaning up the remains on the sites I'm mod on :)

Comment: A recent post on [meta.se]: [Remove 'Autobiographer' from Recent Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376601). (It was marked as status-review.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I asked about this on main meta, since I feel this is a broad, network wide issue, and I came across this entirely by accident.

This... has been going on a while, and our spammers are actually seemingly adapting to be less visible. I can't find the exact question but stuff like not allowing links in profiles is aimed at making the site less attractive to spammers.

[While I asked for a way to delete these accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303746/spam-profiles-are-getting-my-goat-could-we-have-better-tools-for-mods-to-deal-w) - there's far too many to clear out manually, there's a few good ideas suggested to actually prevent them from being able to do this at all. There's also a reasonable awareness that this is a problem so...

While we can't do anything directly - its about 3-4 clicks an account deletion *and* there's rate limits, we've reached out to folks who can do something, both via meta and via other sources.

No promises but we're doing our best to pass this up the chain and suggest ways to deal with it.